# Android sqlite begintransaction executed too long

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to insert data parsed from json into db in batch. I use method bellow to insert batch. Problem is that mDbWritable.beginTransaction(); takes too long to execute. Usually like 6 seconds! I don't know where is problem. Some thoughts what can cause so long execution time? Thanks a lot.

```
@Override
public ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations)
        throws OperationApplicationException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mDbWritable.beginTransaction();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    Alog.i(TAG, "Time applyBatch beginTransaction: " + time);

    final int numOperations = operations.size();
    final ContentProviderResult[] results = new ContentProviderResult[numOperations];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOperations; i++) {
            results[i] = operations.get(i).apply(this, results, i);
        }

        mDbWritable.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } finally {
        mDbWritable.endTransaction();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Some example from logs:

```
11-16 15:14:53.726: I/ApiProvider(21442): Time applyBatch beginTransaction: 6025
11-16 15:15:00.713: I/ApiProvider(21442): Time applyBatch beginTransaction: 4940
11-16 15:15:17.819: I/ApiProvider(21442): Time applyBatch beginTransaction: 8651
11-16 15:15:45.346: I/ApiProvider(21442): Time applyBatch beginTransaction: 12672
11-16 15:16:16.807: I/ApiProvider(21442): Time applyBatch beginTransaction: 12411
11-16 15:16:45.685: I/ApiProvider(21442): Time applyBatch beginTransaction: 12247
11-16 15:17:01.500: I/ApiProvider(21442): Time applyBatch beginTransaction: 12788
```

EDIT: I use apply batch in loop when parsing json. e.g. for each item in json - parse and apply batch. Batch contains insert, update, delete operations.

Here is code how I iterate and call applyBatch

```
Cursor starredChannelsCursor =
        mContentResolver.query(ApiContract.Channels.CONTENT_URI,
                               new String[] {BaseColumns._ID, ChannelsTable.ID, ChannelsTable.SLUG },
                               ChannelsTable.IS_STARRED + "=?",new String[] { "1" }, null);

String userName = mSettings.getUserName();

if (starredChannelsCursor != null && starredChannelsCursor.moveToFirst()) {     
    while (!starredChannelsCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String channelSlug = starredChannelsCursor.getString(2);
        ChannelHandler channelHandler = new ChannelHandler(this);
        URI channelApiUri = Constants.getChannelApiURI(channelSlug,userName);
        //execute update make applybatch call
        executeUpdate(channelApiUri, channelHandler);

        starredChannelsCursor.moveToNext();
    }
}

if (starredChannelsCursor != null) {
    starredChannelsCursor.close();
}


/**
* Make call to Uri, parse response and apply batch operations to
* contentResolver
* 
* @param apiUri
* @param handler
*            - handles parsing
*/
private boolean executeUpdate(URI apiUri, AbstractJSONHandler handler) {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = mHttpHelper.doHttpCall(apiUri);

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> batch =
                    new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    if (apiResponse != null) {
        batch = handler.parse(apiResponse);
        Alog.v(TAG, "update user data from " + apiUri);
    }

    if (batch.size() > 0) {
        try {
            mContentResolver.applyBatch(ApiContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, batch);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alog.v(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: whats the value of `numOperations`?

Comment: usually like 70 , but problem is only in line  mDbWritable.beginTransaction(); as you can see I measure time of this method execution. Other parts are fast

Comment: i think you should take transaction outside of **applyBatch** method

Comment: It's code from Google IO 2012 app and it's correct place for transaction

Comment: Have you run method profiling on this? Stop guessing on what's happening and start profiling!

Answer (score 2):

The only problem which seems to be possible, is that different threads acquire the same lock while calling `beginTransaction()` and waste time just waiting for other threads to release the lock. Have a look at your code and see how you manage threads and from which threads you call `applyBatch(..)` method.

It might be also useful for you to look through the call hierarchy of `beginTransaction()` at [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java/) class.

Comment: I don't know what can block beginTransaction for 12 seconds or so. It's probably because I call apply batch in loop, but it shouldn't because I call beginTransaction after previous transaction was ended.

Comment: According to sources of `SQLiteDatabase` class it may be even be blocked for 30 seconds if accessed from different threads. Could you provide the code from which you call `applyBatch(..)` method?

Comment: Don't you use the same DB anywhere else in your app?

Comment: I use content provider, not Database directly. I am sure that in time when this is running there are no other hard queries.
What I have in mind is that maybe previous iteration mDbWritable.setTransactionSuccessful(); or mDbWritable.endTransaction(); is executed in async so it's possible to iterate to next beginTransaction but it's still blocking db.